# Setup Internet on Raspberry Pi 3 (auto-connect wifi if ethernet goes down)

Tags: wifi, ethernet

I'm brand new to Raspberry Pi 3 but not new to linux or software development and I am gaining a firm grasp on dev ops and networking concepts.

I'd like to setup a fail-safe to maintain an internet connection to my Raspberry Pis and I figured the best way to do this is to only enable wifi and auto-connect to a specific access-point if the ethernet goes down or is unplugged for some reason. And to also detect when ethernet is back online and automatically disable the wifi again.

From what I can tell so far this is feasible by modifying the `/etc/network/interfaces` file.

I'm currently running the Raspbian OS on the device. The network topology is a Modem with a Router and wifi access point on-board. One cable from the Modem Router connected to an 8-port unmanaged switch. And 3 Raspberry Pis connected to the switch.

Is this possible? Or is this even the best approach given the goal? I'm very curious to get all of your feedback.

I don't suspect the internet will go down for any reason, but I'm using this setup to learn about networking, dev ops, and Raspberry Pi.

Thanks for all your help in advance!

Comment: Your question contains insufficient detail to answer. In general the `dhcpcd` networking is quite robust, and you can set routing priorities. See [How to set up networking/WiFi](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697) Fiddling with `/etc/network/interfaces` will only make it **WORSE**.

Comment: what information do you need? And also the link you referenced does suggest to modify /etc/network/interfaces

Comment: You need to specify the network topology, do the WiFi and Ethernet connect to different networks, why do you think your Ethernet will "go down". I suggest you give the default settings a go, and ask a mores specific detailed question if you have problems.